# GWT auto fit composite

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, http, gwt

I have a main Composite that contains SplitLayoutPanel containing StackLayoutPanel on left side and Gwt Map window on right side. How to properly set their sizes and properties so that they always fit the entire browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- set the size of the left component to 100%
- do same for the right component
- fit the main Composite using *Window.getClientWidth()* and *Window.getClientHeight()*

That's how I achieved it, but honestly I am not entirely happy. You have to listen for resize events of window and hardcoded sizes are hard to maintain with different browsers.

By the way, RootLayoutPanel is designed to fit the entire window, so you might want to set composite's size to 100% and place it to RootLayoutPanel and see how does that work :) Please give some feedback about this, I am also interested.

Comment: This was the way to do it before LayoutPanel's were introduced in GWT. With the Layout panels make sure all panels and their parents (up to the RootLayoutPanel) you want to automatically resize based on the browser window size are RequireResize panels (e.g. the Layout).

Answer (score 1):

I think using [ResizeComposite](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ResizeComposite.html) instead of a Composite and adding this widget directly to [RootLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html) should work.

Comment: Yes and to add to this for any more widgets between the RootLayoutPanel and the Split/StackLayoutPanels make sure they are Layout widgets, meaning implementing RequireResize/ProvidesResize and it will all automatically fill the entire browser window.